# Librería Estática Libcurl en C++

Tags: c++, eclipse, curl

Estoy trabajando con un IDE basado en Eclipse (no sé cual versión) con el que compilo programas en C++. Quiero usar la librería **Libcurl** y al solicitar ayuda de los desarrolladores del IDE me dijeron que la única forma de usarla seria creando una librería estática de **Libcurl** de dos formas: bajando los binarios y compilandola yo mismo con ese mismo IDE (me parece usando los archivos dentro de Src) o usando un Makefile para crearla.

Ya intenté bajar la librería y copiar los archivos en la carpeta "src" a un proyecto dentro de ese IDE pero manda muchos errores y llevo horas solucionandolos, ¿Cómo puedo hacerlo con Makefile? ¿Cuáles son los pasos para construirla?